# Stripping HTML markup from a translation string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have some translations that I use in my views. These translations sometimes return very basic HTML markup in them -

```
t("some.translation")
#=> "This is a translation <a href="/users">with some</a> markup<br />"
```

(Side note: I'm using the fantastic [it gem](https://github.com/iGEL/it) to easily embed markup, and specifically links, in my translations)

What if I wanted to strip the HTML tags in certain cases, like when I'm working with the translation string in my RSpec tests. Is there an HTML strp functionality that will compile and remove that markup?

```
t("some.translation").some_html_strip_method
#=> "This is a translation with some markup"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try [strip_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags) from ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

```
strip_tags("Strip <i>these</i> tags!")
# => Strip these tags!

strip_tags("<b>Bold</b> no more!  <a href='more.html'>See more here</a>...")
# => Bold no more!  See more here...

strip_tags("<div id='top-bar'>Welcome to my website!</div>")
# => Welcome to my website!
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you use it.

**strip_tags** method not functioning in **controllers**, **models**, or **libs**

It comes up with an error about **white_list_sanitizer** undefined in the class you’re using it in.

To get around this, **use**:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags('string')
```

To shorten this, add something like this in an initializer:

```
class String
  def strip_tags
    ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(self)
  end
end
```

**Then call it with**:

```
'string'.strip_tags
```

But if you only need to use it in **VIEW**, simply:

```
<%= strip_tags(t("some.translation"))  %>
```